# SVG to android vector drawable

Tags: android

I'm looking for a tool that would translate my svg images to android vector drawable assets. Right now I have to convert my assets one by one by clicking new vector asset -> searching in the folder -> selecting correct svg.
Is there a tool that I could use in a script that would translate all my svg's to android vector drawables(xml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a tool that does the job [SvgToVectorDrawableConverter on github](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter)

Comment: Have you found any similar online tools? The site was down today.

Comment: Well you have the code on github, so you can just download the tool and run it locally.

Comment: I used this instead because I didn't feel like compiling the other project.



https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio by default provides tool to convert svg image to vector drawables.
Here are the steps:
File -> New -> Vector Asset
After that, lot of there will be option from where you can select your local svg and it will be converted to vector drawable.

Comment: Quite painful process if you have to do this for hundreds of images. Hence my question - how to automate it. But this question already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the drawable folder and select ->new vector drawable->from image file ->select the svg and out put path into drawable : This video demonstrates it : https://youtu.be/-nYRhX2LsvQ